# How to configure Shiro with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, shiro

I have a Spring MVC web application that uses Shiro authentication using Spring configuration rather than a shiro.ini.

I want to transition to a Spring Boot application.

I have been mainly successful. The application starts in Spring Boot and my Shiro environment gets setup. However I just cannot work out how to setup the Shiro Filter correctly. I need this to be working to make sure requests end up being handled by the correct thread.

In the original app I configured the Shiro Filter in the web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have tried replicate this using a Java Config like this:

```
  @Autowired
  private WebSecurityManager webSecurityManager;

  @Bean
  public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean() {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(webSecurityManager);
    return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor()
  {
    return new org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  public Filter shiroFilter()
  {
    DelegatingFilterProxy filter = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
    filter.setTargetBeanName("shiroFilterFactoryBean");
    filter.setTargetFilterLifecycle(true);
    return filter;
  }
```

However I just cannot get everything to fit together and don't have enough knowledge to sort it out. I just can't see to connect the filter to the environment. I would guess it is something to do with the order things are setup.

Has anyone managed to use Spring Boot and Shiro together successfully?

Comment: You don't really normally need `DelegatingFilterProxy` in a Spring Boot application. If the `ShiroFilterFactoryBean` creates a `Filter` then it should be applied to all requests by default.

Comment: @Daniel Vaughan Can you share the code base if you have completed it

Answer (score 8):

Well, it seems that the lack of something, java config like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.AnonymousFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.LogoutFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.UserFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.RolesAuthorizationFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.WebSecurityManager;

@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilter.setLoginUrl("/login");
    shiroFilter.setSuccessUrl("/index");
    shiroFilter.setUnauthorizedUrl("/forbidden");
    Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/home", "authc,roles[guest]");
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/admin", "authc,roles[admin]");
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMapping);
    shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
    Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<String, Filter>();
    filters.put("anon", new AnonymousFilter());
    filters.put("authc", new FormAuthenticationFilter());
    filters.put("logout", new LogoutFilter());
    filters.put("roles", new RolesAuthorizationFilter());
    filters.put("user", new UserFilter());
    shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);
    System.out.println(shiroFilter.getFilters().size());
    return shiroFilter;
}

@Bean(name = "securityManager")
public SecurityManager securityManager() {
    DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    securityManager.setRealm(realm());
    return securityManager;
}

@Bean(name = "realm")
@DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public PropertiesRealm realm() {
    PropertiesRealm propertiesRealm = new PropertiesRealm();
    propertiesRealm.init();
    return propertiesRealm;
}

@Bean
public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
}
```

https://github.com/lenicliu/eg-spring/tree/master/eg-spring-boot/eg-spring-boot-shiro

Comment: The answer well suited but still getting:  org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.

Comment: here an example, maybe, it'll help you. https://github.com/lenicliu/eg-spring/tree/master/eg-spring-boot/eg-spring-boot-shiro

Answer (score 2):

lenicliu gave great information, since I can't comment on his answer because I don't have enough reputation. I would like to add all the imports I had to make for his code to actually compile (maybe useful for noobies on Shiro, like me).

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.AnonymousFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.LogoutFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.UserFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.RolesAuthorizationFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.WebSecurityManager;
```

Comment: This should be an edit to the other answer, not a separate answer.

Comment: yes, thank you. As I said I didn't have enough rep to edit the other answer but will do now.