# Spring Boot with Apache Shiro

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, shiro

I'm currently trying to integrate Apache Shiro to my Spring Boot restful API, but am experiencing some issues and was wondering if anyone could help.

My Application.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.xelamitchell.sophia.server")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My WebConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {

        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);

        return servlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {

        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
        registration.addUrlMappings("/sophia/*");

        return registration;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {

        Map<String, MediaType> types = new HashMap<>();
        types.put("json", APPLICATION_JSON);
        types.put("xml", APPLICATION_XML);

        configurer
            .defaultContentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .mediaTypes(types);

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.add(jackson());
        converters.add(jaxb());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson() {

        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.getObjectMapper()
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxb() {

        final Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter converter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {

        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilter.setLoginUrl("/sophia/*");
        shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());

        Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
        filters.put("anon", new FormAuthenticationFilter());
        filters.put("authc", new FormAuthenticationFilter());
        shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);

        return shiroFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager() {

        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(sophiaRealm());

        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sophiaRealm")
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public SophiaRealm sophiaRealm() {
        return new SophiaRealm();
    }

    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

The application start fine, and the logs do show that shiroFilter is being set:

`INFO 12:44:44:271 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/sophia/*]
 INFO 12:44:44:277 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'shiroFilter' to: [/*]`

But when I attempt to access `/sophia/users` I do not get asked to authenticate, the server simply gives me the response.

I was basing my shiroFilter configuration on this question: [How to configure Shiro with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241801/how-to-configure-shiro-with-spring-boot)

Comment: A quick update: After further investigation it looks like Shiro is actually working in the background. In sophia/users method I check if the subject is logged in, if not I call SecurityUtils.getSubject().login with a valid username and password and the user is being checked against my service. It looks like it is a problem with registering the filter correctly to my servlet. Any help is much appreciated as I've been looking at this for a couple of days now with no clue why it doesn't pop up the login form or inform a 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor changes to the shiroFilter fixed the problem:

1. Remove shiroFilter.setLoginUrl(String)
2. Use the following filter chain definition mapping:

```
Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
filters.put("/**", "authcBasic");
shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);
```

And magically the whole API is secured with a Basic HTTP authentication. :)

Uses [Shiro's Default Web Filters](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-DefaultFilters)

Comment: Above isn't quite right.  You need the `setFilterChainDefinitionMap` method. not `setFilters`. i.e.  `Map<String, String> filterChain = new HashMap<>(); filterChain.put("/**", "authcBasic"); shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChain);`.  Then it worked fine for me.