# How to use Apache Shiro for authorization only?

Tags: spring-boot, authorization, shiro

Before I explain the issue I should say that we only need Apache Shiro for authorization and athentication is already enabled with OAuth2.

So my code to enable Shiro is exactly as the code in this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823549/spring-boot-with-apache-shiro).
I have also checked this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388445/apache-shiro-jdbcrealm-with-javaconfig-and-spring-boot). But for me if I enable LifecycleBeanPostProcessor almost most beans will be null. I made that create method in config class static as it suggests in the second link but no luck.

So my question is, is there any way to only enable authorization without registering shiro filter? If not, how to get around this issue? Because it seems ShiroFilterFactoryBean requires LifecycleBeanPostProcessor and that breaks the whole application.

We are using latest version of Spring Boot and Shiro 1.2.4

Comment: Without the filter you would have to do everything it does yourself - you could look at the source for the `LifecycleBeanPostProcessor` and the Filter to see what you need to implement. It might not be all that bad if it's just authorization you need.

Comment: Well.. I checked the code so it seems it looks at AuthorizingRealm and I have created my own AuthorizingRealm to avoid authentication but the problem is that Lifecycle processor when enabled, is breaking Spring and I get NPE. Looks like it's not compatible with Spring boot... I'm still trying to debug every thing here

Comment: I use shiro with boot using the life cycle processor. What is the stack trace?

Comment: There is no error from Shiro or even Spring... the problem is while starting up I get NPE on classes annotated with @ConfigurationProperties. They are all null

Comment: Are you using Gradle or Maven? Did you add the extra plugin required for working with ConfigurationProperties (org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7)?

Comment: No. we're using maven. The application is working fine if I remove the Shiro's filter and LifecycleBeanPostProcessor

Comment: did you advance into it? @xbmono

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-311) in the comments, you would need to set an already authenticated identity in the subject, which can be done with the [Subject.Builder()](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.5.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.Builder.html) (I'm using version 1.5.2 here).

```
Subject user = new Subject.Builder()
    .principals(new SimplePrincipalCollection("bud", "myRealm"))
    .authenticated(true)
    .buildSubject();

if (user.hasRole("admin")) {
    // do some authorized stuff
}
```

When implementing a custom realm the authentication ability can be disabled by returning false from the Realm’s supports method as described [here](https://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#disabling-authentication) .